# Bluegiga BLE112-A: able to program, but unable run see

Tags: in-circuit, bluetooth-low-energy

I tried to get Support from Bluegiga directly, but I didn't get an answer (despite the fact that their Zendesk is nearly unusable):

---

I'm using a [BLE112-A](http://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble112-bluetooth--smart-module/) on our board:

[image]

I've been able to flash my BGScript with the CC Debugger onto the chip, but I can't see it appear in a Bluetooth monitoring app. Flashing the same script onto the development board will show up the chip immediately.

Here's the flash tool's info output from the chip:
[image]

I've checked the docs already, but I cannot see the cause. I've tried it with two of my boards. Any ideas?

Comment: Zendesk for bluegiga is amazing if you read thorough. I have seen questions being answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2):

That schematic is fine. I've powered the BLE112-A with similar setups without issue and the fact you can program it is also a good indication that this is more likely a hardware-software interaction issue. I've had the chips software stall waiting for something to be written out over a hardware interface.

I would do the following:

- Remove USB support from your hardware config, as those i/o lines are not used
- Configure UART to match how it is connected (not possible to see from schematic), i.e. if you haven't connected RTS/CTS make sure you aren't enabling hardware config in you system.
- Remove any writes to hardware you aren't using.

As there's no real debugger for BGScript, one of the best ways to test what happens is to use a simple LED on a GPIO (configured as output) and turning it on in different spots to see what code executes and what doesn't.